# Update Dropdown selection based on other cell

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets: Sheet1 & Sheet2

- Sheet1 has Dropdown menu "Dropdown_1" with choices: a,b,c
- Sheet2 has "Dropdown_2"u, also with choices: a,b,c
- Sheet2 has also a cell linked to the Dropdown menu of Sheet1 "Link_dropdown_1" showing the current selection.

Is there a way how i can update the selection of "Dropdown_2" based on the value in "Link_dropdown_1"? I don't want to synchronise the two dropdown menus bidirectional - just from Sheet1 -> Sheet2. In case my explanation is hard to understand - here is the example in sheets:
[example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Xp9CvEU_cvzO0ZHcagQFw95AFcx8ROF5MDnMp0_D_68/edit?usp=sharing)

**Update:**
Looking for a way to update a Dropdown Menu not a simple cell!

For example: "a" gets selected in "Dropdown_1" --> automatically select "a" in "Dropdown_2" as well.

**Update 2:**
Maybe my previous explanations were really misleading but i am **NOT** looking for a dynamically created dropdown menu or similar. I want to synchronise choices/selection of two dropdown menus that contain the same values.

*Hope this makes it clear:*
[image]

I use "Value_Dropdown_A" for some sorting in Sheet2. In case it its not needed for synchronising "Dropdown_A" to "Dropdown_B" just ignore it...

Comment: @CrazyIvan maybe i am missing something here but i am looking for a way to update a dropdown menu not a plain value in a cell?!

Comment: @CrazyIvan please have a look at my two updates. I still don't see how my question is answered by the threads you linked. Maybe i was not really clear about what i want to achieve, I'm sorry for this!

Comment: I can't reopen your question but @Mogsdad can.

Comment: so this question is now basically doomed?!

Comment: Isn't just putting `=A2` in cell B2 enough for this?

Comment: Not really. The goal is to sync the Dropdown menus both ways. Anyway i will solve it directly in AppsScript - don't think there is a workaround to synch Dropdown menus even one way in sheets